# Why do the inverse t-distributions for small values differ in Matlab and R?

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, distribution, probability

I would like to evaluate the inverse Student's *t*-distribution function for small values, e.g., 1e-18, in Matlab. The degrees of freedom is 2.

Unfortunately, Matlab returns `NaN`:

```
tinv(1e-18,2)
NaN
```

However, if I use R's built-in function:

```
qt(1e-18,2)
-707106781
```

The result is sensible. Why can Matlab not evaluate the function for this small value? The Matlab and R results are quite similar to 1e-15, but for smaller values the difference is considerable:

```
tinv(1e-16,2)/qt(1e-16,2) = 1.05
```

Does anyone know what is the difference in the implemented algorithms of Matlab and R, and if R gives correct results, how could I effectively calculate the inverse *t*-distribution, in Matlab, for smaller values?

Comment: The two cited authorities for the R `qt` C code function are: Hill, G. W. (1970) Algorithm 396: Student's t-quantiles. Communications of the ACM, 13(10), 619–620.  and  Hill, G. W. (1981) Remark on Algorithm 396, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 7, 250–1.

Comment: I confirm that on my machine it fails for the first argument lower than some 1e-16. As for the algorithm, in Matlab you can do `open tinv` and see what it does

Comment: It's also worth pointing out I think that a lot of work has gone into `qt()` (mostly by Martin Maechler) over the years to make sure it works reliably in lots of extreme cases: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commits/trunk/src/nmath/qt.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that R's [`qt`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html) may use a [completely different algorithm](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/qt.c) than Matlab's [`tinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tinv.html). I think that you and others should report this deficiency to The MathWorks by filing a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/). By the way, in R2014b and R2015a, `-Inf` is returned instead of `NaN` for small values (about `eps/8` and less) of the first argument, `p`. This is more sensible, but I think they should do better.

In the interim, there are several workarounds.

**Special Cases**
First, in the case of the [Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), there are [several simple analytic solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#The_Student.27s_t-distribution) to the inverse CDF or [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) for certain integer parameters of *ν*. For your example of *ν* = 2:

```
% for v = 2
p = 1e-18;
x = (2*p-1)./sqrt(2*p.*(1-p))
```

which returns `-7.071067811865475e+08`. At a minimum, Matlab's `tinv` should include these special cases (they only do so for *ν* = 1). It would probably improve the accuracy and speed of these particular solutions as well.

**Numeric Inverse**
The [`tinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tinv.html) function is based on the [`betaincinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/betaincinv.html) function. It appears that it may be this function that is responsible for the loss of precision for small values of the first argument, `p`. However, as suggested by the OP, one can use the CDF function, [`tcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tcdf.html), and root-finding methods to evaluate the inverse CDF numerically. The `tcdf` function is based on [`betainc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/betainc.html), which doesn't appear to be as sensitive. Using [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html):

```
p = 1e-18;
v = 2
x = fzero(@(x)tcdf(x,v)-p, 0)
```

This returns `-7.071067811865468e+08`. Note that this method is not very robust for values of `p` close to `1`.

**Symbolic Solutions**
For more general cases, you can take advantage of [symbolic math](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html) and [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html). You can use identities in terms of [Gausian hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), <sub>2</sub>*F*<sub>1</sub>, as [given here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for the CDF. Thus, using [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) and [`hypergeom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html):

```
% Supposedly valid for or x^2 < v, but appears to work for your example
p = sym('1e-18');
v = sym(2);
syms x
F = 0.5+x*gamma((v+1)/2)*hypergeom([0.5 (v+1)/2],1.5,-x^2/v)/(sqrt(sym('pi')*v)*gamma(v/2));
sol_x = solve(p==F,x);
vpa(sol_x)
```

The [`tinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tinv.html) function is based on the [`betaincinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/betaincinv.html) function. There is no equivalent function or even an incomplete Beta function in the Symbolic Math toolbox or MuPAD, but a similar <sub>2</sub>*F*<sub>1</sub> relation for the [incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) can be used:

```
p = sym('1e-18');
v = sym(2);
syms x
a = v/2;
F = 1-x^a*hypergeom([a 0.5],a+1,x)/(a*beta(a,0.5));
sol_x = solve(2*abs(p-0.5)==F,x);
sol_x = sign(p-0.5).*sqrt(v.*(1-sol_x)./sol_x);
vpa(sol_x)
```

Both symbolic schemes return results that agree to `-707106781.186547523340184` using the default value of `digits`.

I've not fully validated the two symbolic methods above so I can't vouch for their correctness in all cases. The code also needs to be vectorized and will be slower than a fully numerical solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! `NaN` is returned on 2014a. I wasn't aware of the special case analytical solutions. I used `fzero(@(x) tcdf(x,2) - P, 0)` to construct the inverse function at several points, then `interp1`; it is more general, but for `df = 2` it is quite wasteful.

Comment: @Arpi: You're welcome. Good point about solving for the roots using the numeric CDF function itself. I've updated my answer with your suggestion and additional commentary.